# iPhone connected to home Wi-Fi has speeds ~60x faster than Desktop. What might be going on?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, dell-xps, wifi-driver

I am trying to diagnose why my iPhone and Desktop - both right next to each other - experience such drastically different speeds when connected to Wi-Fi. As measured on fast.com, the phone averages about 190 Mbps, whereas the desktop is around 2.9 Mbps. The desktop (a Dell XPS 8700, circa 2015) has always felt slow, but this is the first time I've seriously looked into the problem.

I'd appreciate any pointers you guys may have. Here's what I've tried so far, but the issue persists, and I've reached the limits of my troubleshooting ability. (Edit) In response to a user comment, I have provided a screenshot of connection settings on the two machines, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOYpB.png).

- Assumed it was a measurement issue. Laptop (MS Surface) and phone (iPhone 8 - with cellular data disabled for good measure) both clock in around 190 Mbps. The issue is solely with the desktop
- Assumed it was a driver issue (the original adapter is a Dell Wireless 1703 - on the motherboard) so downloaded and updated from Dell website - no effect
- Assumed it was a weird Windows issue, so did a clean install of Windows 10 Pro (10.0.18362 Build 18362) and installed all Windows Updates - no effect
- Assumed it was a hardware issue, so bought and installed a TP-Link AC1200 PCIe Adapter, to replace the original adapter. Confirmed in adapter settings that the Dell 1703 is disabled, and the sole wireless connection enabled is the TP-Link - no effect
- (Edit) Assumed it might be something more broadly wrong with the motherboard, so connected the machine by Ethernet cable instead - excellent speeds [D: 300 Mbps / U: 290 Mbps / P: 3ms] but sadly impractical
- (Edit) In response to a suggestion from the comments, I tried Speedtest.net instead of Fast.com. At the time of editing, speeds are higher - but equivalent - on both tests. Speedtest gave [D: 15.09 Mbps / U: 16.30 Mbps / P: 5ms] while Fast gave [D: 15 Mbps / U: 15 Mbps / P: 6ms]

I have since run out of ideas...

Comment: Try Speedtest.net to compare with and see if you get the same results

Comment: Two things: first, your iPhone may be compatible with a more recent, better performing version of WiFi (say, WiFi 5) than your PC, which would explain why it gets a faster downlink; secondly, your access point will emit at a certain rate (say, 300Mbps for WiFi n, or WiFi 4 as they call it these days) on a double range of frequencies (2.4GHz and 5GHz), but maybe your PC can't accomodate those speeds, so your access point will throttle down on the standard it uses to grant access to the slower WiFi 3 (b/g) your PC WiFi card can tolerate, hence the difference in speeds.

Comment: @Didier - Adapter incompatibility isn’t the issue.  Please read the entire question.  The author specifically purchased a WiFi 5 adapter.  iPhone 8 doesn’t support WiFi 6 at this time.

Comment: I've read the (long) entire question, and I'll stick to my guns: maybe the PC just can't accomodate the speed its brand-new WiFi adapter could give it, were it (the PC) more recent, so the adapter is throttling down, not electrically or thermally speaking, but in terms of data rate. An iPhone 8 can connect on the 5GHz range, but most probably the PC can't, even with the new adapter, so the access point will give the phone full speed on the 2.4GHz, or downplay the 5GHz speed, and the PC will get what its motherboard will allow, new adapter or not, because it's got PCIe 2.0, not 3.0.

Comment: Possible, but a 2015-era machine should have decent wireless. My 2013 laptop keeps up with my phone. That is why I suggest trying a different external speed test site.

Comment: Try to connect PC and router with cable. If still slow, then i think a new question should be opened - with the result of [Dell hardware diagnostics](https://www.dell.com/support/article/de-de/sln283546/how-to-run-hardware-diagnostics-on-your-poweredge-server?lang=en).

Comment: @furty - Commenting here (and will update the question accordingly). I have using the cable in the past, and data speeds are excellent. It a fine solution, but I do prefer not to run a long cable across the room :)

Comment: @ John - I updated the question. The two sites give the same result, more or less

Comment: @Didier - I'm not sure how to tell if what's on the board is PCIe 2.0 or 3.0. The new adapter is connected on Slot #24, on page 13 (https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_xps_desktop/xps-8700_owner%27s%20manual_en-us.pdf). How does one tell from this?

Comment: Thanks, have you tried with different antenna positions? Can you post a screenshot of your router's connection details with the PC compared to other devices?

Comment: @Furty - Just tried; antenna positions don't seem to make a difference. Re: connection details, do you mean an ipconfig output from two different devices?

Comment: @Furty, I edited the post with a link to a screenshot as requested.

Comment: No, as i said from the router (open 192.168.99.1 in browser). Maybe someone else has the same combination of PCIe card + router model and can give advice. If the router does not show any connection speed, does Windows say the speed is excellent or poor? Btw i had a good experience with a TP-Link USB Wifi years ago - with such the antenna positioning is much more flexible.

Comment: The most common reasons are the driver or the mobile device is high end and has a better SD card and software. The HDD on the PC can not run with such a high speed.